# Entity Framework Core v.5+ many-to-many fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

If I have two classes "Node" and "Viselement" that are in a many to many relationship. Is it then possible to give the name of the join table itself?
But I don't want the collections in the classes Node and Viselement to point to the join table. I want to leave the classes node and viselement as they are but define the name of the join table itself, which is currently generated by ef core.
I could not find out yet how to do this and if it works at all. Does anyone have an idea?

I need to change the joining table name because it does not fit the naming conventions of the DB.

```cs
public class Node
{
    public Node()
        Viselements = new HashSet<Viselement>();

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string OriginTableName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Viselement> Viselements { get; set; }
}

public class Viselement
{
    public Viselement()
        Nodes = new HashSet<Node>();

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string DbNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

It then generates this by itself:

```cs
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "NodeViselement",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    NodesId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
                    ViselementsId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_NodeViselement", x => new {x.NodesId, x.ViselementsId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_NodeViselement_node_NodesId",
                        column: x => x.NodesId,
                        principalTable: "node",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_NodeViselement_viselement_ViselementsId",
                        column: x => x.ViselementsId,
                        principalTable: "viselement",
                        principalColumn: "id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_NodeViselement_ViselementsId",
                table: "NodeViselement",
                column: "ViselementsId");
```

Now i would like to define the tables name as "node_viselement" and not "NodeViselement" and the id's from "NodesId" to "id_node" and "ViselementId" to "id_viselement".

What do I have to do in the DbContext so that this can be achieved?

But i don't want to end adding the join table to the classes:

```cs
    public virtual ICollection<NodeViselement> NodeVises { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the stuff that is generated in the database, you have the edit the Migration that was automatically generated.

I do not know if there is a another/better solution, but if there is, please avoid this one. Editing the migration can lead to various issues when upgrading/downgarding migrations, and can result in a situation where you have to apply the migrations from ground zero.

### Changing the names in the Migration

To change the table name, you will have to modify the `CreateTable` part like this:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "node_viselement", 
    ...
```

You can simply change the **name** of the table that will be generated. This is the first step.
Now carefully browse through the whole file and find all the references to this table and update all of them to the new name. Like here:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_NodeViselement_ViselementsId",
    table: "node_viselement", // <-- edit here
    ...
```

To change the columns, you basically have to do the same except you won't be editing strings. Just change `NodeId` and `ViselementsId` here to their new names:

```cs
columns: table => new
{
    id_node = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false),
    id_viselement = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uuid", nullable: false)
},
```

Like with the table name, you will have to find all references to these as well and edit them accordingly.

Comment: Thank's for answering, but the problem in your solution is, you have to chang code in ContextModelSnapshot.cs which is self generated. If you change code on the migration. it is only changed on the databases but not in the c# model. And changing self generated code, i want avoid.